# Block list as tree in magento controller function

Tags: magento

How can i get the list of blocks render or load from a specific controller function for example catalog-> category -> view

I need it for get the idea which one i will remove or unset from my local.xml

Answer (score 0):

$this->loadLayout('catalog_category_view');

refer this link: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/digging-deeper-into-magentos-layout-xml-part-2/

Comment: I need the list like the tree : 

catalog_category_default
            -> content
                -> category.products
                    -> product_list
                        -> product_list_toolbar
                            ->product_list_toolbar_pager

I am not sure about the possibility

Comment: you can switch on hint from admin to get .phtml and block details.